# PHP zip extract and rename

Tags: php, zip, file-rename

The code below sort of works.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if($zip->open($path) === TRUE) {
   $zip->renameName('list.csv', 'list'.$batch_id.'.csv');
   $zip->extractTo('list_output');
   $zip->close();
}
```

The file inside the zip is renamed, but it does not extract. If I remove the renameName line then it extracts fine. I need it to do both.

Comment: See what happens if you close the zip and re-open between the two operations.

Comment: did you try renaming it after you unzip it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about?

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if($zip->open($path) === TRUE) {
   $zip->extractTo('list_output');
   $zip->close();
}

rename('list_output/list.csv', 'list_output/list'.$batch_id.'.csv');
```

Would be easier on the CPU/Memory too.

Comment: Crazy fast answer, I'll use this method, still curious why what I have doesn't work, but your method is better.

Comment: My best guess, You need to close it. And reopen.